# Como implementar o ng2-img-max do Angular?

Tags: angular

Meu problema é o seguinte;

Estou conseguindo salvar e exibir as imagens utilizando minha API, porém no momento de exibir as imagens em tela ela fica estourada, ou seja, as minha imagens são de resolução de 4800 x 3255, é uma resolução muito alta, eu poderia redimensionar uma por uma pelo PhotoShop, porém um colega de trabalho me indico essa tecnologia logo abaixo;

[ng2-img-max](https://alligator.io/angular/resizing-images-in-browser-ng2-img-max/)

O que ela faz é antes de salvar ela redimensiona a imagem. 
Eu já instalei e configurei o projeto para receber o **ng2-img-max**

Esse abaixo é exatamente o código que precisa ser concluído;

Antes estava assim;

```
 public filesToUpload: Array<File>;
    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
      this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    }
```

E modifiquei para ficar assim;

uploadedImage: File;

```
  public filesToUpload: Array<File>;
    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
      this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;

      this.ng2ImgMax.resizeImage(this.filesToUpload, 400, 300 ).subscribe (
            result => {
              this.uploadedImage = result;
            },
            error => {
              console.log(<any>error);
            }
          );

    }
```

Porém está gerando esse erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E veja onde está o erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro está na linha 88, apesar de saber onde está o erro eu não sei como corrigir o erro, preciso de ajuda.

**Uma das minhas tentativas, porém não tive sucesso;**

```
uploadedImage: File;


    public filesToUpload: any;
      fileChangeEvent(event) {

        let filesToUpload = event.target.files[0];

        this.ng2ImgMax.resizeImage(filesToUpload, 400, 300 ).subscribe (
              result => {
                this.uploadedImage = new File([result], result.name);
              },
              error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
              }
            );

      }
```

Comment: Parece que vc esta passando um array e ele so aceita um elemento de cada vez.

Comment: Eu acho que é isso mesmo, porém não sei como corrigir  a lógica, eu fiz uma tentativa, gostaria que desse uma olhada, ele tirou o erro porém na hora de executar ele não salva a imagem na pasta.